# Javascript getElementById - reading works, altering doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have this pretty complex ajax thing going. 
It loads new html (including div tags and all) to show up on the page.
I included a 'more' link to load additional data.

This more link links to my javascript function. The 'more' link is located in a div, which I gave a unique id. The next time the load function is called, I use document.getElementById(the id).style.display="none"; to "remove" this div from the look of the page.

I set error traps for this, the div with that id is found without problems, but javascript fails to change my style property.

I tested alert(document.getElementById(the id).innerHTML); and that worked without problems - hence the title of the question.

So, does anyone have any ideas/do I need to offer more information? The main problem is that it doesn't throw any errors anywhere, yet it fails to complete the task I asked...

Here's a bit of code to go with it -

```
try 
{
    var myidthing = "morelink" + ContentStart.toString(); //the id is correct
    var div = document.getElementById(myidthing);
    if (!div)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        div.style.display="none"; //this doesn't work, but doesn't raise an error
        alert(div.innerHTML); //this works without problem
    }
}
catch(theerr)
{
    alert(theerr);
}
```

------------------------->EDIT<-------------------------
I'm incredibly sorry if I upset any people.
I'm also angry at myself, for it was a stupid thing in my code. Basically, I had a variable that stored the contents of a parent div. Then I (succesfully) removed the div using the removeChild() method. Then my code pasted the contents of that vaiable (including the div I wanted gone) back into the parent div. 
I switched around the order and it works fine now.

Again, excuse me for this.

Comment: Can you post the code so we can take a look? This should work (although you could use a framework and make this much easier on yourself).

Comment: Does your browser's error console show any errors?  In firefox it's Tools->Error Console (Ctrl+Shift+J).

Comment: I'll try to put the important parts of the code together in a minute.
Also - frameworks... My project has gotten far too big to introduce a framework now. While not using a framework, I still learn quite a lot of basics - which I like.

And there were no errors that could possibly have an influence. Besides, I set an error trap..

Comment: All browsers? Just IE? Just FF? Other?

Comment: ditto, what browser are you testing. A rudimentary demo seems to work in FF3.5, IE6, IE8: http://jsbin.com/icudo (Editable: http://jsbin.com/icudo/edit)

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that the div with that id is generated by javascript too - but before this function should work.

I tested in Chrome 3.0.195.27, Shiretoko (Firefox 64bit) 3.5.2.

The thing that bothers me the most is that it manages to read from it, but fails to change.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more code or context. I added a div into the DOM and set its display attribute without any problems. It looks like brianpeiris was also unable to repro.

Comment: never use document.getElementById - it doesn't always work in IE. use a javascript toolkit like dojo or JQuery or write a more robust alternative.

Comment: Here's the deal - it's something simple that should work. Now integrating a toolkit/framework in the project would be far more work than necessary for just one little thing that messes up.

A more robust alternative? for getElementById? any suggestions?

Comment: MICHhimself: "It should work" according to whom? It's obviously *not* working, so until you can provide everyone on SO with more information I very much doubt you'll receive any further assistance. "Integrating" jQuery is a single javascript include, whereupon you can use its services as much or as little as you would like. Good luck.

Comment: The thing that bothers me is that all you people seem to have to offer is 'use a tooklit instead'.

It should work because I've used the exact same method of hiding a div like that multiple times before, without any problems.

I would provide more source, but it's such a whole divided up thing.
I'll try to figure it out on my own then.

Comment: I think you can see from Brian's, Matt's and my response that we ARE trying to help you, and none of us can replicate your issue. I literally took the exact code you posted and cannot replicate your issue. It's working fine for me.

There must be something else going on in your code.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

Throwing out a few ideas of things to look for:

- You said the div is generated by javascript. Is it possible the div you are targeting is not the one you think you are? It could be you are targeting another div, which is already hidden, or obstructed... or maybe the innerHTML you are displaying goes with a different element than the one you intend to target. Put an alert or script breakpoint in the if(!div) case, also, and see if it's going down that path.
- If the above code is only a stripped-down version of your actual code, check your actual code for typos (for example: style.display = "none;";)
- Using the FireBug plugin for FireFox, inspect the target element after the operation completes, and make sure that the display: none appears in the style information. If not, use FireBug's debugger to walk through your javascript, and see if you can figure out why.
- Use FireBug to break on all script errors, in case there is another error causing this behavior.

Comment: All helpful pointers. I tried quite a few of them before actually. I'm 100% sure it's that exact div I'm targeting (alerted the generated div id, alerted the div id it tries to contact) - plus it's the right div as I can *read* the data from it.
Typos have been check and rechecked to no end.

I'll give Firebug a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Try empty quotes instead of 'none' and see if that works?:

```
document.getElementById('element_id').style.display="";
```

Failing that, don't change the style, just add a class which hides the element.